# Android - Losing data switching between google map and web browser

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, oncreate

My application displays a map with some markers using the Google map API. If i select a marker, the application offers me the possibility to open a browser to a specific URL based on the marker's title. When going back to the app, I think it enters in the onCreate function; as a consequence I'm losing the state (camera position for example) the application was before browsing. Is there  way to avoid that or some kind of backup-restore mechanism?

Here is my manifest, as asked by @DavidWasser

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: When returning to the app it shouldn't call `onCreate()` on your activity again. You must be doing something strange. Please post your manifest and indicate which activity is the one that is losing state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at your code and realized that it's not what I ment, take a look a the code below:
That's how you can save a state:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And how to restore it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_search, container, false);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilise MapViews [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) method by calling it from within [activity's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) or [fragment's onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) method. Use it to restore MapViews state in fragment's onCreateView().
That should save camera position, zoom information etc.

Remember to follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html) (class overview section) about hooking up your MapViews methods

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna test it and I will tell you the result.

Comment: I'am glad to hear it helped.
If my answer helped you please mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the code that works fine for me (thanks @MatRos):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

   if (mMap != null) {
       outState.putParcelable("camera", mMap.getCameraPosition());
   }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        CameraPosition savedCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("camera");
        if(savedCameraPosition != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(savedCameraPosition));
        }
```